# Android save state for dialog

Tags: android, dialog, radio-button, save, state

How do you save the state of a dialog in android? I have the following dialog with radio buttons but can't figure out how to save the state of the dialog. Thanks for any help

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Tweaks.this);
builder.setTitle("Pick an item");
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}).show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the position of the selected item when the user clicks.  Then you look for a previously stored index when you display the list.  If there is no previously stored value you return -1.

I have an app Preferences helper class ...

```
public class AppPreferences {
     private static final String APP_SHARED_PREFS = "myApp_preferences"; //  Name of the file -.xml
     private SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs;
     private Editor prefsEditor;

     public AppPreferences(Context context)
     {
         this.appSharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
         this.prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
     }

     public int getItemIndex() {
         return appSharedPrefs.getInt("itemIndex", -1);
     }

     public void saveItemIndex(int i) {
         prefsEditor.putInt("itemIndex", i);
         prefsEditor.commit();
     }
}
```

Then, in my code I create a field variable ...

```
protected AppPreferences appPrefs;
```

And instantiate an instance of it inside the Activity onCreate() ...

```
appPrefs = new AppPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

Then replace your "-1" with ...

```
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, appPrefs.getItemIndex(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
```

And in your onClick() make sure you ...

```
appPrefs.saveItemIndex(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

I saved the state in member variables in the DialogFragment. The following code saves the state when the dialog is closed, but **not** when the app is closed.

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    //this is the default value, set when the dialog is created
    private String myValue = "any initial String"; 
    private TextEdit myTextEdit;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //construct the dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        ViewGroup myView = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, null);
        builder.setView(myView);

        //find the view and set the value
        myTextEdit = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.my_text_edit);
        myTextEdit.setText(myValue);

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);

        //when the dialog is dismissed, save the users input and overwrite the initial value
        myValue = myTextEdit.getText();

    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at my answer that is what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use preference but i would recommand to use the new androidx design pattern. Basically, saving dialog state should not be saved when application is closed. That is we want (so we don't need preferences or something like that).

You can use android view model and saved state to do this work.

Here is a link to show dependencies and versions to use with gradle (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle)

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:1.0.0-rc01'
```

You can do like this.

```
public class HelloAndroidViewModel extends AndroidViewModel{
    private SavedStateHandle mState;

    public HelloAndroidViewModel(SavedStateHandle savedStateHandle) {
            mState = savedStateHandle;
    }

    public void saveParam(int param){
        mState.set("key", param);
    }

    public int getParam(){
        Integer param = mState.get("key");
        if(param != null){
            return param.intValue();
        }
        // default value
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {

  HelloAndroidViewModel viewModel;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new SavedStateViewModelFactory(getApplication(), this).get(AndroidViewModel.class);

 }
```

Then you can use value to retrieve and store with your dialog.

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Tweaks.this);
builder.setTitle("Pick an item");
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, viewModel.getParam(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        // save ui state
        viewModel.setParam(item);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}).show();
```